# Specifying which ArcSDE feature class Geoprocessing Service is to update?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to have a geoprocessing service update sde.  I am getting an I/O Error saying data doesn't exist.  I imagine because the connection file (copied from my ArcCatalog folder) I placed next to the script isn't working through digital osmosis.

I found an answer on GIS.se [outlining](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10503/creating-a-gp-script-to-update-a-table-in-sde) some steps to have a geoprocessing service write to sde.  I have successfully hit sde with desktop script tools.

Do I need to log on to the server as the arcgissoc user and build database connections?  Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You need a GP service on the server and the SDE connection needs to be on the server, as well.  The script that the tool in the Geoprocessing Service uses will need to be told where to find the SDE conn file i.e. \\servername\folder\folder\your_sde_connection_file.sde\SDEfeatureclass

Assuming you are a user with permission to be on the server.  I would not use the SOC account.

Here is greater detail on connecting to the server
Use ArcCatalog on your PC to make a connection to the server (use ArcCatalog "Connect to Folder" to make the server connection under Folder Connections) you'll need to find your location/make a folder. Add the scripts and an SDE connection file to this folder that you will copy/paste from ArcCatalog Database Connections. Create the toolbox here. In ArcCatalog section of GIS Servers (you may need to add yours) right click the server and "Add Service". Use the toolbox from your Folder Connections for your new geoprocessing service.

Comment: So is there an arcpy method that builds a connection?

Comment: I don't have ArcCatalog on the same server where ArcGIS Server sits.  Or at least I can't find it.

Comment: Nice answer. I encourage you to fold the extended procedure in the comments into the answer itself, so it's cohesive and all in one place. (see the [edit] link in light grey at bottom left of the post).

Comment: Thank you.  I did edit the answer with my comments, and deleted the comments.