# Finding definitions of ArcGIS script parameter Data Type options?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

When adding a python script to a toolbox in Arcgis one of the steps is to [set parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/) and specify what Data Type each requires. The list is long, perhaps a hundred, and many are not immediately understandable. For example I just tried to require data type "Database Connections", but when I run the tool and select "Database Connections\Connection to foobar.sde" I'm told the item is invalid. Aww nuts.

Now I could just ask *"what is the "Database Connection" data type?"* here on GIS.se and get on with my work, but then tomorrow I'll have to do it again for *Disk Connection* and *Decimate*. (might do wonders for my reputation level though...) So lets just get 'em all in one go, I hope:

**Where do I find the definitions of all the Data Types available for tool parameters?**

[image]

Comment: also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23742/definitions-of-arcgis-script-parameter-data-type-options

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See 'Geoprocessing_data_types.pdf' in [Data types for geoprocessing tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/supplement/data-types-for-geoprocessing-tool-parameters.htm)

To answer your specific question, I belive you would want to use a Workspace parameter which will let you specify an SDE connection file, then use filters to limit the workspace type (see screenshots in comment below).

Comment: Is this one way you could update sde with a gp service. I couldn't figure out how to do that so I just wrote to a shapefile. Check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22516/how-do-i-tell-my-geoprocessing-service-which-sde-feature-class-to-update

Comment: No idea about GP services, sorry.

Comment: thanks! Dunno how I missed that, since I did see that page in my searches; had my no-pdf's blinkers on I suppose. And for nitpicking clarity: the answer to my problem is use Workspace parameter (but that doesn't restrict to sde workspaces, which was the initial goal), and the answer to the specific question is *"The `Database Connections` worktype is The database connection folder in ArcCatalog."*

Comment: You can specify a filter for Workspaces: [Step 1](http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/1742/22caad0d2f384b7cba3ef31.png), [Step 2](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/5122/11d64bc746b44721a290c8b.png)

Comment: I converted the pdf to html table and a few other possibly useful formats, see https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/tree/master/docs