# What parameter's data type is Short integer in arcgis 10.3 model builder?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool

I am defining a parameter for a python script in model builder. The script calculates a single value from a featureclass using a formular referencing values of a long integer field in the same table. This value will be used as a variable for another tool in the model which is defined as a short integer. I therefore need to set the parameter in the script setting to "output" so that I can use the variable elsewhere and set the data type. 
Which data type should I use for small integers?

Comment: how to look up all data types: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23742/definitions-of-arcgis-script-parameter-data-type-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use Long (derived). This will be automatically stored in your field as a short integer if the absolute value is small enough (< 32767), but this will be an issue when its larger, so make sure that your model handles the case when the user enters a value that will yield an "out of range" output.